# Calling JavaScript functions between script tag blocks

Tags: javascript

I have two sets of `<script>` tag blocks containing JavaScript functions and have put them in priority orders. One of the tags contain a `src` to another external .js library file as shown below.

```
<script src='libtest.js'>
    function helloworld() {
        alert('hello world');
    }

    function callLibraryTest() {
        runLibraryTest(); //Calls into libtest.js for auto test.
    }
</script>

... some html ...

<script>
    function callHello() {
        helloworld();
    }
</script>
```

The error I am getting is the `callHello()` function does not have the `helloworld()` defined. How do I solve that ?

Note that the scripts are deliberately separated because if they were bunched up, calling the `callHello()` might end up not defined as well.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes - src: `This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not have a script embedded within its tags.`

Comment: I don't understand your remark about `callHello()` not ending up being defined. If you put it in a `<script>` tag then it will be defined, whether it is in there with other functions or not. What made you concerned that they must be in separate script tags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a `<script>` tag has a `src` attribute, it cannot also contain script text. Move the `helloworld` function to a separate `<script>` tag.

```html
<script src="libtest.js"></script>

<script>
    function helloworld() {
        alert('hello world');
    }

    function callLibraryTest() {
        runLibraryTest(); // Calls into libtest.js for auto test.
    }
</script>

<!-- some html ... -->

<script>
    function callHello() {
        helloworld();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to run "callHello" function when "libtest.js" is loaded successfully. As Dan already explained that a  tag with src attribute cannot contain javascript code in its body. 
You can try a trick like callback method. For example modify the src tag to "libtest.js?callback=callHello" and at end of the libtest.js execute the callback method.

Hope this helps!